# ubuntu server name resolution order

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, domain-name-system, winbind

I am using LAMP on Ubuntu server, and I need to query MSSQL database on Windows XP machine, both on the same network. I use winbind to resolve SMB hostnames. My problem is name resolution order. It first tries to resolve using primary DNS, then secondary, and finaly resolves to the XP machine. The problem is when internet connection fails primary and secondary DNS servers are not available, so it resolves using winbind after primary and secondary DNS time out (and database connecton). How do I move winbind to the top of the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this through the /etc/[nsswitch.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) file. Make sure that [wins](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/winbindd.8.html) is listed before your other name services

```
hosts:    wins file dns ...
```